# when processing start open new window in c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading

I'm working on a project in c#.net, a password generator. My problem is that when the password is generated a new window form opens and shows "please wait". My main form is inactive until processing is complete. I already use showdialog, which works, but it stops my main form processing. Help me, what can I do ?

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit difficult to help if don't see any code.. but I make some working sample for you with entire flow:

```
    BackgroundWorker worker;
    Form dialogForm;

    private void buttonGeneratePassword_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler( worker_DoWork );
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler( worker_RunWorkerCompleted );
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();

        dialogForm = new Form(); // dispay your dialog
        dialogForm.ShowDialog();
    }

    void worker_RunWorkerCompleted( object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e )
    {
        // password generated.. close dialog form
        dialogForm.Close();
    }

    void worker_DoWork( object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e )
    {
        // put generate password code here
        Thread.Sleep( 1000 ); // delete this line - it is only for testing flow without password generation code
    }
```

Hope it help you..

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Show()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.show.aspx) instead of `ShowDialog()`

Comment: With Parent set to main form.